# Value of 2D Array not being change by switch statement

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

I am trying to code a game of Tic-Tac-Toe, but for some reason my `switch` function doesn't appear to be running. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int n = 0;
int Player[2] {1, 2};
int moveChosen=0;
int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;


void Display(int grid[][3], int row, int column)
{
    cout<<"Coordinates: \n";
    cout<<"1"<<" | "<<"2"<<" | "<<"3"<<"\n";
    cout<<"--|---|--\n";
    cout<<"4"<<" | "<<"5"<<" | "<<"6"<<"\n";
    cout<<"--|---|--\n";
    cout<<"7"<<" | "<<"8"<<" | "<<"9"<<"\n";
    
    
    cout<<"Current Moves: \n";
    cout<<grid[0][0]<<" | "<<grid[0][1]<<" | "<<grid[0][2]<<"\n";
    cout<<"--|---|--\n";
    cout<<grid[1][0]<<" | "<<grid[1][1]<<" | "<<grid[1][2]<<"\n";
    cout<<"--|---|--\n";
    cout<<grid[2][0]<<" | "<<grid[2][1]<<" | "<<grid[2][2]<<"\n";
    

}

int moveChoice(int Choice)
{
    cout<<"Player "<<Player[n]<<" please pick where to move. ";
    cin>>Choice;
    
     if (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9)
        {
            while (Choice < 1 || Choice > 9)
            {
                cout << "Invalid choice, please enter a new number: ";
                cin >> Choice;
            }
        }
    
    return Choice;
}

void CheckMoveValid(int grid[][3], int Choice)
{
    
    
    switch (Choice)
    {
        case 1:
            if(grid[0][0] != 0)
            {
                cout<<"Invalid move, space already filled. ";
                
            }
            else
            {
                moveChosen = Player[n];
                n1 = 0;
                n2 = 0;
                break;
                
            }
            break;           
        case 2:
            if(grid[0][1] != 0)
            {
                cout<<"Invalid move, space already filled. ";
            }
            else
            {
                moveChosen = Player[n];
                n1 = 0;
                n2 = 1;
                break;
            }
             
        
    }
   

}



int main()
{
    int grid[3][3]={{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
    int Choice, CheckWin = 0;

    
    while (CheckWin < 1)
    {
      Display(grid, 3, 3);
      
      moveChoice(Choice);
    
     CheckMoveValid(grid, Choice);
     
     if (n=0)
     {
        n = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        n = 0;
     }
     grid[n1][n2] = Player[n];
     
     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I put `cout << "0" << endl;` between line 65 and 66, nothing happens even when I enter `1`, and whatever I tried I could not get `"Invalid move, space already filled. "` to trigger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You will learn of several mistakes in this code if you only [turn on compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/K34GKa37v)

Comment: FYI, `if (n=0)` is wrong, it should be `if (n==0)` instead. And the `if` in `if (condition) { while (condition) { ... } }` is redundant, just use the `while` by itself.

Comment: *"If I put [code] between line 65 and 66"* -- **1)** Which lines are 65 and 66? (Expecting readers to count lines is a bad idea.) **2)** Why are there so many lines in your [mre]? Why does your main function do more than `int main() { int grid[3][3]={{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}; CheckMoveValid(grid, 1); }`? No user input required, and you get to eliminate two function definitions. *(Well, either you get to eliminate the unused functions or you discover that the problem can be demonstrated without `CheckMoveValid`. Either way, it's debugging progress.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, the call to `moveChoice()` prompts the user for input, but then discards that input.  The `Choice` variable in `main()` is never assigned a value, so the call to `CheckMoveValid()` exhibits *undefined behavior*.

Get rid of the `Choice` parameter in `moveChoice()`, it is not needed. Have `main()` assign the return value of `moveChoice()` to the `Choice` variable, eg:

```
int moveChoice()
{
    int Choice;
    ...
    cin >> Choice;    
    ...
    return Choice;
}

...

int main()
{
    ...
    int Choice;
    ...
    Choice = moveChoice(); // <-- HERE!!!
    CheckMoveValid(grid, Choice);
    ...
}
```